# Fill two separate arrays with data?

Tags: python

I am trying to fill two separate arrays in Python, one will contain the value numbers, and the other will be the weight. The array is as follows

```
res = [2, 3, 72, 17, 44, 23, 31, 24, 1, 26]
```

Basically the 3 indicates that there will be 3 sets of items, where val should = 72, 44, and 31 and wt should = 17, 23, and 24. How do I fill two separate array variables with these figures?  Here is what I have so far but I think I'm overthinking it.

```
nCount = 1

N = res[1]

val = []

wt = []

while nCount < N * 2:
    for x in range(N):
        val = res[nCount + 1]
        print(val)

    for y in range(N):
        wt = res[nCount + 2]
        print(wt)
        nCount += 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slices to get your arrays:

```
items_count = res[1]
values = res[2:2 + items_count * 2:2]
weights = res[3:3 + items_count * 2:2]
```

`res[2:2 + items_count * 2:2]` means select each `2` element from `res` starting from element with index `2` to element with index `2 + items_count * 2`. You can read more about slices [here](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how-do-i-use-the-slice-notation-in-python).

Comment: Even if your code answers the question please add some description.

Answer (score 0):

**Using len(list)**

res[2:len(res)-2:2]

res[3:len(res)-2:2] or res[3:len(res)-1:2]